# How can I run this contract in Remix?

Tags: solidity, remix

I want to run contract-f87aacb4e7.sol in Remix. But error occurs like
"Running contract-b2bfbf7ec7.sol ...
pragma is not defined"
How can I fix it? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you didn't set the compiler version at the top of `.sol` file.
`pragma solidity =0.8.18;`
You can find compiler version at the top of compiler tab in the left panel.